# connecting to a remote host with ansible-vault encrypted private key does not work

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-vault

I can ssh to a remote server if I use the ansible command module

e.g

```
tasks:

 - name: ssh to remote machine

   command: ssh -i key ansible@172.16.2.2
```

However as this will be stored in github, I encrypted the private ssh key with ansible-vault.
Once I rerun the same command with the vault decryption password (--ask-vault-pass) it will not connect. It's as if the encryption/de-encryption does not return the same ssh key.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My legendary colleague found a solution if anyone else comes across the same issue.

[Ansible SSH private key in source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392369/ansible-ssh-private-key-in-source-control)

You need to copy your encrypted ssh private key to another file first to decrypt it and then you can use it e.g.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    source_key: key
    dest_key: key2
  tasks:
  - name: Install ssh key
    copy:
      src: "{{ source_key }}"
      dest: "{{ dest_key }}"
      mode: 0600

  - name: scp over the cert and key to remote server
    command: ssh -i key2 ec2-user@1.1.1.1
```